# Diferencia entre elemento input y elemento button de tipo submit en HTML

Tags: html

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre estos dos elementos al momento de usarlos para desencadenar un evento? ¿Existe algo que la otra parte no pueda hacer? (aparte de no poder usar el elemento `input` fuera de un elemento `form`)

Comment: El elemento `input` se puede usar fuera de un elemento `form` para crear interfaces de usuario y se seguiría considerando HTML válido (hay una nota sobre esto en el último párrafo de la [sección de controles](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#idx-control-7)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mira con los dos puedes desencadenar eventos, comunmente el 
`<input type="submit">` es usado para enviar formularios y aplicaciones de esos tipos, pero también puedes darle diferente uso claro, mientras que el tag `<button type="">` es usado en un aspecto mas de aplicación y desencadenar eventos u acciones manejadas por java script u otro lenguaje un ejemplo del tag `<button>` es que quieres que al dar click cambies el color de cierto elemento.
Y por otra parte no es que no puedas utilizar el `<input type="submit">`, lo que pasa es que por lo regular aplica las acciones cuando este está dentro de un `<form>` pero puedes cambiar el comportamiento de este por medio de eventos de JavaScript

Answer (score 5):

En lo que se refiere a eventos, `<button type="submit">` e `<input type="submit">` son equivalentes.

La única diferencia (y no entre las dos etiquetas) en cuanto a eventos sería el comportamiento de `<button type="submit">` en navegadores antiguos, en los que  podría enviar valores diferentes: en algunos casos (IE6) sería el texto contenido entre las etiquetas, y en otros casos sería el valor especificado en el `value`.

Aparte de eso, la principal (¿única?) diferencia entre `<button type="submit">` e `<input type="submit">` es el tipo de contenido que se puede presentar con cada uno de ellos. El primero puede contener elementos HTML (p.e.: texto + imágenes) mientras que el segundo sólo puede contener texto:

```html
<input type="submit" value="Pulsar <img src='http://lorempixel.com/20/20/' />">
<hr/>
<button type="submit">Pulsar <img src='http://lorempixel.com/20/20/' /></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra diferencia importante es que en `<input type="submit">` el click solo funciona dentro del value o texto del botón. En cambio en `<button type="submit">` funciona en todo el botón, incluyendo padding.