# <input type=“button” /> vs. <button> en HTML

Tags: html

Actualmente estoy trabajando con formularios HTML, algunos de ellos recogen datos y los envían al servidor para consultar o actualizar datos en una base de datos remota MySQL.

He visto que los botones para iniciar acciones pueden ser declarados como:

- `<button>`

o como

- `<input type="button" />`

Probando una posibilidad o la otra realizan la misma función, así que me surgieron algunas dudas, todas ellas relativas a crear formularios con los elementos más adecuados para cada caso.

¿Existe alguna diferencia entre ellos?

¿Habrá casos en los que se recomiende usar uno u otro?

¿Ocurre algo si se usan combinados en un mismo formulario?

¿Podría haber problemas de compatibilidad?

Son varias preguntas, pero supongo que las respuestas no serán tan amplias.

Comment: Habría jurado que esta pregunta ya se había hecho en Stack Overflow en Español. [Edición] Hay [una pregunta muy parecida que hizo dwarandae](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/3422/250), pero realmente no son iguales

Comment: Pero... la comunidad de programadores hispana tiene _también_, derecho  a buenas respuestas en el idioma de Cervante. @CarlosGª-muñoz

Comment: @a-cedano pues tiene toda la razón del mundo... Que viva Cervantes y a postear!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Traducido desde la [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5), es de la documentación de html4 pero aún es válida:

> Los botones creados con la función de elemento BUTTON funcionan igual que los botones creados con el elemento INPUT, pero ofrecen posibilidades de renderización más enriquecidas

**Respondiendo a tus preguntas:**

¿Existe alguna diferencia entre ellos?

> Si, aunque su finalidad es la misma, lanzar una acción(incluso podríamos englobar los `<a></a>` entre ellos también.) La diferencia principal va más por los estilos, la forma y la finalidad.
>
> - **input**: Permite crear un simple botón que **solo puede incluir texto** en su atributo `value` y es lo que se muestra en el botón.
> - **button**: Permite crear un botón pero con html dentro, o sea **puedes incluir iconos, imágenes, etc.**
> - **a**: Permite incluir html dentro, iconos e imágenes, como si fuera un botón pero por definición y semántica los enlaces te deben llevar a otro lado(puede ser contenido traído por ajax) mientras que los botones deben realizar una tarea.

¿Habrá casos en los que se recomiende usar uno u otro?

> Si, como mencioné en las diferencias, básicamente por cuestiones estéticas.

¿Ocurre algo si se usan combinados en un mismo formulario?

> No, puedes usarlos de forma indistinta, incluso sin un formulario. Ambos se pueden usar fuera del formulario sin problemas.

¿Podría haber problemas de compatibilidad?

> No, no habría ningún problema, ambos son parte del estándar de html y solo son como dos elementos diferentes, eso si se debe respetar las demás reglas de html como que no deben repetir el id.

Answer (score 5):

> ¿Existe alguna diferencia entre ellos?

Sí, hay dos grandes diferencias:

1. `<button>` te permite utilizar otras etiquetas para cambiar el formato del botón, mientras que `<input type=button />` no te lo permite.

Ejemplo:

```html
<button><h1>Texto grande!</h1></button>
<br>
<button><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basicset/tick_64.png"/> Con imagen</button>
```

2. `<button>` se comporta como `<input type="submit" />` cuando está dentro de una forma, mientras que `<input type=button />` no.

Ejemplo:

```html
&lt;button&gt; dentro de forma:
<form action="/test" method="get">
  <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
<br>

&lt;input type="button"&gt; dentro de forma:
<form action="/test" method="get">
  <input type="button" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
<br>
```

> ¿Habrá casos en los que se recomiende usar uno u otro?

Generalmente utilizarías `<button>` para mejorar el contenido del botón sin tener que recurrir a *CSS*, aunque la realidad es que la mayoría de las veces terminarás utilizando *CSS* para estilizar tu botón.

`<input type="button">` lo utilizarías más cuando quieres enviar una forma utilizando *javascript*, así evitarías la necesidad de utilizar `preventDefault()` para evitar que la forma se envíe (como lo hace un `<input type="submit">`).

> ¿Ocurre algo si se usan combinados en un mismo formulario?

Simplemente uno si enviará la forma (`<button>`) y el otro no la enviará (`<input type="button">`). Fuera de eso, no te afectará dentro de la forma.

> ¿Podría haber problemas de compatibilidad?

Podrías tener problemas con `<button>`, pero únicamente exploradores viejos, como lo son *IE6* o *IE7*.

Answer (score 2):

Esta pregunta ya la hicieron en el **stackoverflow** en inglés y un usuario recomendó un enlace muy bueno que te lo explica detalladamente y con imágenes.

[Rediscovering the button element](https://web.archive.org/web/20110721191046/http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/)

Lo bueno de la etiqueta ***button*** es que es una etiqueta que necesita cerrarse por lo cual puedes introducir ***HTML*** dentro de ellos, como por ejemplo, una imagen. 
A su vez, pueden aplicarse estilos ***CSS*** de una manera mas óptima y crear botones mas interactivos y fluidos para el usuario.

En conclusión, que la etiqueta ***button*** te ofrece una lista mas amplia de posibilidades que su alter-ego input.